# Oracle CRM On Demand Stateless web service access

Tags: web-services, oracle, crm, stateless, ondemand

I've seen statements on various Oracle.com properties that claim Oracle CRM On Demand has the capability to access its webservices in a stateless manner however I can't seem to find any documentation on what exactly this entails.

Has anyone ever successfully invoked a stateless request with Oracle CRM On Demand or have any pertinent information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire webservice document is available throught the CRM environment...

Admin>> Web Service administration >> Download documentation

Comment: That document has left me with the sentiment of "water water water everywhere and not a drop to drink", that it actually doesn't really seem to document anything actually useful about stateless sessions in it's nearly 550 pages of stuff.

Comment: @Chris - Yeah, the documentation isn't much help and neither are the forums.  I did a CRM on Demand integration recently and basically gave up trying to do a stateless request and just went with the 'stateful' request.

Answer (score 0):

from admin ->  Company Administration
set of the flag  "Web Services R16 Compatibility Mode"
Now each Request will be stateless and will use the existing session Id for your login user.
it is writtnen on the document!!